Is there any frontend send request code example when the backend API use @login_required from Flask-Login?
I want to implement frontend to send logout request to the flask backend below,
from flask_login import login_required, logout_user

@app.route('/auth/logout', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return "success", 200

I only know I should include the credential information inside the POST data.
However, even I read through the document:
https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
and google on the internet, I didn't find a working example of frontend code that works with this kind of backend API
Is there anyone who can provide a simple frontend code example to call this backend api with credential included, thanks!

I got a practical code example for sending request to this API:
fetch('https://app_hostname.com/auth/logout', {
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': getCookieValue('XSRF-TOKEN')
  }
});

CURL command should be:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json, 'Accept': 'application/json', 'X-XSRF-TOKEN: xxxx'" 'https://app_hostname.com/auth/logout'

Inspired by: https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/patterns.html#using-a-cookie

No credential information is needed, you will not be making a post request. Login system works with cookies. Meaning when you delete the cookie from the browser, you are logged out.
Therefore it's trivial to logout by visiting a link in the html. And then flask-login will delete the user from the session, logging you out.
from flask_login import login_required, logout_user

@app.route("/auth/logout")
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for(<your_homepage>))

You simply need to put the following link to your navbar or on the profile section etc..
...
<a href="url_for('logout')">Logout</a>
...


Hi @Bck, thanks for the answer,
However, I am not using template/xxx.html as frontend, instead, I want to develop a customized react or other js based frontend to send request to my flask backend
So I am looking for the example of sending request to this endpoint

Have you tried a simple anchor tag that points to your logout route? <a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a>

For example, there is code example for react and flask-jwt-extended in
https://dev.to/nagatodev/how-to-add-login-authentication-to-a-flask-and-react-application-23i7
But I couldn't find example for react and flask-login in the internet yet

The point is I didn't use the redirect(url_for(<your_homepage>)) as logout page in my application
I build up the logout page in react by my own, so I can't redirect to the built-in templates instead
